# Why is it that Dart's DateTime.parse rolls to january next year when trying to parse the "13" month?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, parsing, datetime-format

When working on a Flutter/Dart project where I had to parse different methods entering dates into a form, I found that if the user wrote i.e (by accident) '09.13' for december 9th (wrote 13 instead of 12), the parse result for parse rolled over to january next year.

Given in code:

```
DateFormat format = 'dd.MM';

try{
  var dateTime = format.parse('09.13');
  print("dateTime = ${dateTime.toString()}");
}on FormatException{
  print("dateTime error");
}
```

I expected this to be

```
dateTime error
```

but instead I got

```
dateTime = 1971-01-09 00:00:00.000
```

I understand the reset to 1970, since I didn't give any year, I'd rather expect it to give a `FormatException` to show the user that there is a flaw in the entered date... ...but rolling over to the next year (1971) and give no Exception ?

Is there any reason for this behavior, or do I simply need to fight with RegEx for this dateTime check...

Comment: Can you include more about `DateTimeFormat`

Comment: It's probably that `DateTime.parse` (or  `DateFormat.parse`) don't perform range checks at all and pass them directly to the `DateTime` constructor, and `DateTime`'s constructors automatically convert invalid dates.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, sorry, it was a misspelling, I have changed it to `DateFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually, not something to fix, the `DateFormat` algorithm was made to calculate the expected DateTime from the input:

9 days and 13 months logically equal 1 year, 1 month, and 9 days.

However, using `dart` you can throw your own custom `FormatException`, as example you could do something like this:

```
   try{
    String stringDate = "09.13";
    if(checkMonthLimit(stringDate)) {
     
     var dateTime = format.parse(stringDate);
     print("dateTime = ${dateTime.toString()}");
     
     } else {
     
     throw FormatException("some text here");
     
     }       
      }on FormatException{
     
     print("dateTime error");
    
     }

   bool checkMonthLimit(String txt) {
   return int.parse(txt.split(".")[1]) <= 12;
   }
```

Now if the month is above 12, the method will return false, so it enter the else block, then throws the `FormatException`, which will be catched in the catch block.